# Flutter application not running in the android device, but it's works in another devices. How to fix it?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle, apk

When I try to run the app on a Physical Android device, it shows an error message like this. But, it's working on another device. I already used this device to launch my previous projects. And I didn't change anything. How can I fix this issue?..

**Error:**
[image: Error]

I tried changing the V2signinconfig but not been fixed yet.

Comment: Please do not post terminal output as a screen shot. Simply copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code.